# Find all strings except one string using regex

Tags: regex

I want to match all strings except the string `"ABC"`.
Example:

```
 "A"     --> Match
 "F"     --> Match
 "AABC"  --> Match
 "ABCC"  --> Match
 "CBA"   --> Match
 "ABC"   --> No match
```

I tried with `[^ABC]`, but it ignores `"CBA"` (and others).

Comment: I believe this has been discussed lengthily at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word.

Comment: @wombat, that other question is about rejecting a string that *contains* a certain substring.  This one is about the special case of a string that consists entirely of `ABC`.  `AABC` and `ABCC` are okay.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

```
^(?!ABC$).*
```

matches all strings except `ABC`.

Comment: I think he wants all combinations of 'A' 'B' 'C', right? (i.e. in any 3-length string)

Comment: @d'alar'cop `CBA` should be matched according to the examples

Comment: but then shouldn't his [^ABC] work? if not, how come?

Comment: @d'alar'cop `[^ABC]` will reject `CBA`

Comment: Ah, ok, I think I simply misunderstood your regex. '?!' is negative lookahead, right - what is the following '$'? (excuse my ignorance)

Comment: @d'alar'cop: It matches the end of the string. Otherwise, the regex would reject `ABCD`, too.

Comment: Ahh.. ich sehe jetzt. I didn't realise one could put the $ anchor inside in that way. Nett. Vielen Dank.

Comment: I also tried with negative but never get it works, because I didn't use an ending position inside. Thanks Tim!

Comment: That's what I got:
`var some = /^(?!ABC$).*/; 'ABC asdfas  asdfasdf'.match(some)
result: ["ABC asdfas  asdfasdf"]`
I think it should't include ABC here

Comment: @developer: The author of the original question obviously thinks differently (see example number 4 and the comments under the question and Bohemian's answer). You seem to have misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 3):

Judging by you examples, I think you mean "all strings except those containing the *word* ABC".

Try this:

```
^(?!.*\bABC\b)
```

Comment: @Bohemaian: No, I mean "all strings except this specific string 'ABC'"

Answer (score 1):

### Invert the Match with GNU Grep

You can simply invert the match using word boundaries and the specific string you want to reject. For example:

```
$ egrep --invert-match '\bABC\b' /tmp/corpus 
"A"     --> Match
"F"     --> Match
"AABC"  --> Match
"ABCC"  --> Match
"CBA"   --> Match
```

This works perfectly on your provided corpus. Your mileage may vary for other (or more complicated) use cases.

Comment: Your demonstration works perfectly, however I have no something like "invert-match" in my case. Thanks!