# Regex that removes everything except specified string

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am working with data that looks something like this:

```
{"score":0,"compare":0,"words":["book","planet","sun","science"],"words":[],"good":[],"bad":[]}
{"score":-1,"compare":0,"words":["book","planet","sun","science"],"words":[],"good":[],"bad":[]}
{"score":1,"compare":0,"words":["book","planet","sun","science"],"words":[],"good":[],"bad":[]}
```

The only information that I am interested in is the **"score":#** (which could be either positive or negative).
Since I am working with thousands of lines that look like above, I am trying to extract only the score information that I am interested in using a `regular expression`.

I have consulted various posts, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15852869/find-all-strings-except-one-string-using-regex), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404010/match-everything-except-for-specified-strings) and [here](http://www.emalis.com/2012/09/replace-select-all-except-a-string-with-regex-and-notepad/), for example, but none of them seem to address my problem.

I have used them to try to write my own regular expression. Thus far, I have tried things such as:

```
(?!"score":(-)?[0-9])

^(?!"score":(-)?[0-9].*

(.(?!"score":(-)?[0-9]))*
```

but each of these examples selects *ALL* of the information, including what I am interested in.

How can I modify these regular expressions to arrive at my desired result, which is:

```
"score":0
"score":-1
"score":1
```

Comment: Why not just match your desired text?

Comment: These are JSON strings, and if they appear line by line, you can read the file line by line, parse the string and get the `score` value. Why use regex?

Comment: I was trying to find a solution that would automatically remove all of the other information that I am not interested in. This information is one column in a rather large TSV file, which was why I wanted to isolate that information.

Comment: Are you using a programming language for this? It would be a very simple thing to do with python, for example. Or are you just using a text editor?

Comment: Use [`.*("score":[-+]?\d*\.?\d+).*`](https://regex101.com/r/qU8eU4/1), replace with `$1`. If you need no float number support, just `.*("score":[-+]?\d+).*` is enough.

Comment: I was just using a text editor at the moment because I thought it would be something much simpler than it ended up being.

Comment: @stribizhev it worked great. Why don't you put your proposal as an answer?

Comment: @owwoow14: Posted, let me know if you need any more clarifications. I will go on drinking coffee :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexps do not work as expected:

1. [`(?!"score":(-)?\[0-9\])`](https://regex101.com/r/pB9wY6/2) matches empty spaces before each symbol that is not followed with `"score":\d+`
2. [`^(?!"score":(-)?\[0-9\].*)`](https://regex101.com/r/pB9wY6/1) matches empty space at the beginning of a line
3. [`(.(?!"score":(-)?\[0-9\]))*`](https://regex101.com/r/pB9wY6/3)  matches every symbol but the opening `{`.

You can use

```
.*("score":[-+]?\d*\.?\d+).*
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qU8eU4/1)

Replace with `$1`.

If you need no float number support, just use

```
.*("score":[-+]?\d+).*
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/qU8eU4/2)

The main concept is matching all the line and capture the substring we need (`"score":<number>`). Then, we revert the captured text in the replacement string.

Here,

- `.*` - matches any number of any characters other than a newline
- `("score":[-+]?\d*\.?\d+)` - matches

  - `"score":` - `"score":` literally
  - `[+-]?` - either literal `+` or `-` (you can keep either - adjust for yourself)
  - `\d*\.?\d+` matches floats (with no thousand separators)
    or
  - `\d+` - matches a sequence of 1 or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a development sample here:
https://regex101.com/r/yL7hA9/1

it is:

```
"score":(-)?[0-9]+
```

feel free to modify to your requirements.